# fscanf() text only reading

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read text file using fscanf() with `%[]` specifier.
File like this one:

```
qwety, qwe<

qwety,qwety.... qwety
```

So, I need to read only text without any separator like comma, space, dot..
Looking for answer said something like that, but it's doesn't work properly: successfully read only first word and go to never ending loop

```
char buff[1024];
while(!feof){
    fscanf(file, "%[a-z]", buff);
    puts(buff);
}
```

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: No, problem with fscanf() only, cos I read always only one word instead of five

Comment: `while (!feof)` will never loop. `feof` is a function which turns into a function pointer in this context. It never has a value that is false (`NULL`), so negating it is always false. Maybe that's just a typo, but then, that just shows that you should have provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, after reading the first word into `buff`, the next characters in the file (your input buffer) are not `a-z`, so all subsequent calls to `fscanf` fail with a *matching failure*. To fix the problem, reverse the *character class* and use the *assignment suppression operator* (`'*'`) to read and discard any non-`a-z` characters, e.g.

```
while (fscanf(file, "%1023[a-z]%*[^a-z]", buff) == 1)
    puts(buff);
```

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%1023[a-z]"...` and `fscanf(file, "%*[^a-z]"....` should be separated.  This answer's `"%1023[a-z]%*[^a-z]"`  consumption of non-letters requires a prior successful read of letters.  This answer prints nothing if the first character of the file is a non-letter.

Comment: Well, point made, but I was simply working on the question asked, not all that could have been asked. If we were to separate, and condition a `break` on the first, we would end up in the same boat. Now we could `getchar()` and `ungetc()` as an initial test -- which would alleviate the problem. A `fgets` (or `getline`) with the 1st char test followed by `sscanf` would also make more sense from a robustness standpoint.